# pytest-django ERROR django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-models, pytest, pytest-django

I have a Django project with pytest and pytest-django packages. I have an app "api" with **tests/** folder with all of my tests. After running pytest in the terminal, I get an error:

```
==================================================== short test summary info ===================================================== 
ERROR apps/api/tests/test_db_queries.py - django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must eithe...
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! 
======================================================== 1 error in 0.45s ========================================================
```

I have a test to test my User model. When I don't use my model and delete import from api app everything is working fine. `settings.py` is in **meduzzen_backend** folder.

test_db_queries.py:

```
import pytest
from api.models import User

# Create your tests here.
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_queries_to_db():
    User.objects.create(username="sfdf")

    users = User.objects.all()
    assert len(users) == 1
```

My project hirearchy:

```
├───.pytest_cache
│   └───v
│       └───cache
├───apps
│   └───api
│       ├───migrations
│       │   └───__pycache__
│       ├───tests
│       │   └───__pycache__
│       └───__pycache__
├───code
└───meduzzen_backend
    └───__pycache__
```

My `tests/` folder has `__init__.py` file.

pytest.ini:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = meduzzen_backend.settings
python_files = tests.py test_*.py *_tests.py
```

Where is the problem?

I've tried to rename my api app in `INSTALLED_APPS` setting in `settings.py` from:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ ... # Django apps 'api.apps.ApiConfig', ... ]`

to:

`INSTALLED_APPS = [ ... # Django apps 'api', ... ]`

I've tried to add these lines of the code:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'meduzzen_backend.settings')
import django
django.setup()
```

I also tried to delete `__init__.py` file. but there is another error that api.module hasn't been found.

Comment: If you run a django project in Docker. You need to add ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=<project_name>.settings to Dockerfile to solve this problem